# ¿Como puedo leer una tabla muy grande en RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo una tabla de aproximadamente 20 millones de registros, cuando la acceso vía find, funciona perfecto, pero necesito leer registro por registro desde el primero hasta el último para extraer cierta información y eventualmente actualizar otras tablas menores para estadísticas, pero me da un error: anexo extracto del código y su error:

**Código:**

```
registros = Nacional.all.order('id ASC')
registros.each do |ente|
   puts "alguna logica"
end
```

**error:**

```
[FATAL] failed to allocate memory
```

Estoy seguro que debe existir una forma óptima de leer una tabla muy grande, y he buscado, pero hasta ahora no he encontrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola Puedes intentar con `find_each` que te dará 1000 registros a la vez

```
Nacional.find_each do |nacional|
  # tu logica
end
```

tambien como parametro puedes pasar `batch_size` para aumentar la cantidad de registros al tiempo

```
Nacional.find_each(batch_size: 5000) do |nacional|
 # tu logica
end
```

Aqui te dejo mas información [find_each](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each)